# Running SQL Server & IIS on same Windows server without making site go slow

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, iis

I have a dedicated Windows 2008 Server with 32GB RAM & Intel Xeon E3-1230 v2 processor and SQL Server 2008 (Standard Edition).

There's a heavy data import & cleaning process i.e importing data from CSV files which runs daily and whole process takes about 8-10 hours.

My problem is that ASP.NET MVC website which is hosted on this same sever gets slow for small periods during that import process. Most of the time, it runs fine, but in between, the site will become unresponsive and slow. The import process doesn't touch the database which the site uses.

1. What are the options for me to ensure my site runs smoothly throughout?
2. is it even possible to achieve, keeping in mind some very resource-heavy operations get performed during the data import on the same server?

The import process is a Windows application which uses SSIS packages to import data and after that runs server SQL Server stored procedures.

Comment: There is nothing much that can be done. One thing that you can take care of is try to run the heavy job at times when site recieves very low traffic. If possible, you can outsource the process to another server

Comment: The trouble is that if the import process takes up all the available memory as well during the peak times, IIS have to wait in line until it becomes available again. Will it be possible to break up the import in smaller chunks? What kind of process is done by the MVC website? Would it be possible to divide the processing of the CSV-file into different steps?

Comment: @DanieSchoeman Import process is not like one file import. there are hundred's of csv files. And a lot more happens after getting these files into db as well. We call it matching. Something like you see on price comparison websites.  MVC website is pretty simple. It simply shows the data prepared by the import process.

Comment: Do you know at what stage during the import the heaviest processing is done? @RahulNeekra's answer looks like a good solution. If you do not have separate  hardware you have to apply a stepped change. I suggest to first create and move all data across for the SQL Server. Make sure all connections is changed appropriately. The create the web server and move across.

Comment: As import process does not use the same database of web site, is it possible for you to create a separate instance for import process db and set max cpu and memory for import process using Resource Pools https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934084.aspx

Comment: @anil Thanks sir for your suggestion. Just to be clear by instance you mean seperate Sql Server Instance that will be used by import process? Also As I know Resource Governor is not available with Standard Edition. Which we are using.

Comment: yes, seperate Sql Server Instance,  Developer and Evaluation editions are not intended for production environments. In that case you can go with @Rahul

Comment: One Alternative:  Limit your SQL Server to only use up to a maximum amount of memory.   This can help IIS make sure it has at least a certain amount of memory left over.  In your specific case it may be SSIS and possibly SSRS that actually need to be limited in memory.   Start with knowing how much memory SQL and SSIS are actually using at different times through the day and during the slow time – this may give you a clue.  Also – if this server is virtual then more details are relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ankit quick solution for your problem is to have 2 VM on your dedicated hosting server. One one  VM you can host your website and another VM you can host you database and import process.

From performance perspective it is case by case as your problem is very generic and broad so community can't help but tip still you can follow.

1. For your website create separate application pool.
2. You can assign min and max CPU and memory utilization for your processes like import, IIS etc based on your need.
3. Check clock speed;whether it is matching between your processor and virtual memory. It doesn't matter how much virtual memory you have you need your RAM in sync with you processor cores.
4. As SQL Server Standard version supports max 4 cores of processors. Check how much cores you have in your dedicated server.

Comment: these looks like some good suggestions. I am not really a Server Admin so not sure how I can create VM's. Can you guide me to  some place where I can learn how to do this.  Along with that can please provide answers to these question 1.) Will I need to install window & SQL Server in both VM's then? 2.) Can I assume with VM's in place Both my website & import process will get predefined capacity of resources?

Comment: For VM creation you need to have software few guidelines whihc you can get from youtube.

When it comes to your questions
1. No you don't need to install SQL Server on both VM's otherwise whole purpose of VM creation will defeat. Windows installation will require to be installed on both machine but SQL Server you can install on eother one. 
2. As you will create two VM which will share hardware resources of you physical machine. So you can allocate resources as per your need. If you need more resources for import process get it separated from website hosted VM.

Answer (score 1):

I have got some really good ideas from the community for my problem. Having two Virtual machines is a very good one but it's restricted by my lack of knowledge on the topic. Solution proposed by Anil in comments in also a good one that we can two seperate SQL Server instance and use Resource governor to restrict resources but for that we'll have to first upgrade to enterprise edition which is not feasible for us at the moment.

So keeping the cost in mind, we have decided to try Varnish. Plan is to get a separate Linux VPS and set Varnish there. Window Server will be the backend for Varnish. As once the data is prepared by our import process, our pages stays more or less static, I think we'll do good with this.